# does live DVD totally erase windows?

Tags: format, livedvd

I'm buying a new laptop august 13th, the Asus X551MAV-RCLN06 is the front runner. It has the Intel Celeron N2830 dual core processor, 4 gb ram. The two options with the Live DVD are to use the whole disc or load beside Windows. It says all files will be erased if the whole disc is used. Is the whole disc reformatted in this process, or is it just given a new index? I prefer that the whole drive is returned to zeroes and ones so that there's no chance that Windows can interfere with my computer's functioning. Do I need to do something special for that, or does the Live DVD take care of it? I'm getting the latest Ubuntu, the 14.04LTS. The reason I ask this is that once I reformatted a 500 GB HDD, and it took 36 hours. I know loading Ubuntu only takes an hour or so, and that doesn't seem like enough time to return a HDD to a blank condition before loading the new OS. Thanks!
PS If there is a good reason for me to load Ubuntu beside Windows, I will entertain doing that. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use the whole disk, Ubuntu will use the `ext4` filesystem everywhere, meaning anything in NTFS partitions is lost to all but professional recovery tools. Actually zeroing the disk isn't necessary, but if you want to do that, simply run:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`

Where `/dev/sda` is the ID of the disk (check using the `lsblk` command).

Comment: If I were to load beside Windows would Ubuntu run just as well?

Comment: @PatrickDeBoard If it uses UEFI Secure Boot and Windows 8, you may have problems, but there are plenty of questions here on AU which deal with that. If you were to discard anything preinstalled and install Windows yourself, I think you will only have reinstall GRUB, everything else should fine.

Comment: I've decided the Lenovo G50 is now the  laptop I want. 421.99 @ Best Buy. It comes with Windows 8.1. I think I'll leave Windows on there and load Ubuntu beside it.